# Powershell - split array into more column with conditions

Tags: powershell

I have made a script in Powershell which adds extra column. However, I want to set a condition for the second column.

```
PS H:\> function ArrayToHash($table)

{
    $hash = @{}
    $NUM = read-host "input "
    $table | foreach { if ($table -gt $NUM){$hash[$_] = $_ }else{"too small"}}
    return $hash
}
```

The desired should be:

```
Col1        col2
-----      ------
numberA    numberB
```

But right now, it shows:

```
Col1        col2
-----      ------
numberA    numberA
```

I need some suggestions, how to add the condition to makesure the result only shows on col2.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that in your ForEach-Object loop you are comparing the whole array to the input, where you should compare each item of the array separately.

Next, it is unclear which number you want as key and which number should be the value in your Hashtable..
Also, is `$table` an array of integer numbers, or strings or what? Remember that using `Read-Host` allows the user to enter all kinds of characters and in your code there is no check whatsoever on that.
There is also no escape possible if the user wants to quit.

Then, a Hashtable will never output what your desired output should be, because it only has Name and Value, so if you want `Col1` and `Col2`, you need to convert the hash into a `PsCustomObject`.

Assuming you call the function with an integer array, then you could do something like this:

```
function ArrayToHash([int[]]$table) {
    $NUM = Read-Host "Input a number. Type Q to quit"
    # quit if no input or anything starting with `Q`
    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($NUM) -or $NUM -match '^q') { return } 
    # test if the user entered something that can pass as integer number
    if ($NUM -match '^\d+$') {
        $hash = @{}
        $table | ForEach-Object { if ($_ -gt $NUM) {$hash[$_] = [int]$NUM } else {"$_ is too small"}}
        # convert the hash into a PsCustomObject. The shortest way to do that is by using
        # Select-Object and calculated properties
        $hash.GetEnumerator() | Select-Object @{Name = 'Col1'; Expression = {$_.Name}},
                                              @{Name = 'Col2'; Expression = {$_.Value}}
    }
    else { Write-Warning "$NUM must be numeric" }
}

ArrayToHash (1..10)
```

Your console output will then be:

```
Input a number. Type Q to quit: 6
1 is too small
2 is too small
3 is too small
4 is too small
5 is too small
6 is too small

Col1 Col2
---- ----
  10    6
   9    6
   8    6
   7    6
```